# Open Source alternatives to push notifications by Google's FCM or Amazon's AWS SQS?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sqs

Though I'm politically neutral when it comes to app development, the recent and sudden kill-switch put on Parler by AWS left me a bit uneasy about dependency upon a proprietary system owned by one of the big tech firms. I think I'd prefer to stick with open-source software.

I'm using MySQL as my database and need to send push notifications to a topic on a Flutter mobile app whenever a row is inserted. Can anyone suggest an open-source alternative to Google's FCM or AWS's SNS/SQS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer, but rather my experience over the last month.

I agree and have been researching alternatives with my DevOps. It seems that even though you can find open source SDKs out there, you still have to go to Google, Apple and Amazon for the actual push. This and the iron grip on their App Stores needs to end up in court.

I have pulled my Apps and focusing on Browser Based (with flutter). Everything hosted offshore ... but, will not be able to do push notifications without going through big tech.

Comment: Thanks. I had a sinking feeling this was the case...

Comment: I'm thinking instead of push notifications I could use streambuilder and livestream updated json from an opensource database. I'm currently looking at Rethinkdb even though it failed commercially. It still seems like there is a bit of a community. I suppose if you go opensource with everything but the push notifications it wouldn't be the end of the world if Big Tech decided to pull the notifications. At least you'd still have your main opensource database and data.

Answer (score 1):

You can try AeroGear UnifiedPush Server

> The AeroGear UnifiedPush Server is a server that allows sending push notifications to different (mobile) platforms and has support for: * Apple’s APNs (HTTP/2) * Firebase Cloud Messaging

It's similar to FCM has a rest api for sending push messages and basic topic and aliaes support. Has client libraries for android, ios and cordova. It's documentation not perfect but works mostly.

https://github.com/aerogear/aerogear-unifiedpush-server

https://aerogear.org/push/

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer with guidelines from the guide.